# root_certificates.hpp in boost should be specific?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, boost-asio, boost-beast

I'm new in SSL concept , Sorry I don't know my question is correct or not ...

Recently I wanna know [root_certificates.hpp](https://github.com/ceph/Beast/blob/master/example/common/root_certificates.hpp) should be specific for every clients? I mean that clients should create it by openssl?? or it's general and all clients can use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`root_certificates.hpp` is only there to make the examples portable.

On your system, you typically can use [`set_default_verify_paths`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ssl__context/set_default_verify_paths.html).

If your application additional requirements, which is often, you will want to include your own certificate store in the way that your application chooses. There are more details to customize the verification process: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ssl__context.html (see also https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ssl__stream/set_verify_callback.html).

Comment: Oops , your right and boost documents has some explaination that I saw that now. https://github.com/boostorg/beast/blob/develop/example/common/root_certificates.hpp#L38  Thanks.